# Is it possible to "forward" a FireWire 400 port to a FireWire 400 port in OS X?

Tags: firewire, mini-dv

I have the following situation:

I have a camera with a mini-DV port, and a cable which brings the mini-DV to FireWire 400. The only problem is that I need to ultimately get from the mini-DV port to the FireWire 800 port on my MacBook Pro.

Unfortunately, FW 400 != FW 800, as I found out trying to shove a 400 into an 800. It just doesn't work.

I was thinking that I could have an old iMac G4 (two FW 400 ports) somehow 'forward' one of the ports to the other, because I have an FW 400 > 800 cable.

Is this possible, or is there a better way?

Comment: What is a mini-dv port? Do you mean the format is miniDV? The port might be micro-USB or something along those lines?

Comment: @Raystafarian [the non firewire end of this](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=9SIA1HE0NX4672&nm_mc=KNC-GoogleMKP&cm_mmc=KNC-GoogleMKP-_-pla-_-PDA+Accessories-_-9SIA1HE0NX4672) is probably what they mean...

Comment: @Raystafarian It's marked as simply DV on the port.

Comment: @nerdwaller Yep.

Comment: Then yes, a 400 to 800 adapter would be the solution

Comment: @Raystafarian Really what I'm asking is how to forward everything from FW A to FW B on OS X 10.4

Comment: Why go through the G4 when you can get a cable adapter [female 400 to male 800](http://www.amazon.com/Sonnet-FireWire-400-Adapter-FAD-824/dp/B0000CDJPQ)? It can go straight from the camera to the macbook.

Comment: @Raystafarian Because then I would have to buy something, and that's cheating :) I got it working with the G4.

Answer (score 0):

As was written in the comments, a Firewire 400 to 800 adapter is the best solution to this problem.  I use one to connect DV video cameras, and older disk drives to my Mac mini, which only has a Firewire 800 port.  All the Firewire 400 devices work without problem.

Comment: I got it working sharing the 'internet connection' of the G4 to my FW 400 > 800 cable. A little hacky, but I didn't have to buy anything!